# Arcpy - Convert point in WSG84 to EPSG:2056

Tags: arcpy, coordinate-system

Currently, i have some points in WSG84 coordinate and i want to convert them to EPSG:2056 using this snippet:

```
coordList = [[46.34188, 8.02521], [46.34191, 8.02525], [46.34195,8.02516], [46.34188, 8.02521]]
polygonArray = arcpy.Array()
for p in coordList:
  point = arcpy.Point(p[1], p[0])
  ptgeo = arcpy.PointGeometry(point, in_spatial)
  ptgeo1 = ptgeo.projectAs(out_spatial)  
  pt1 = ptgeo1.lastPoint  
  polygonArray.add(pt1)
```

This snippet will produce this result:

```
2645081.068384 - 1132306.244629
2645084.122581 - 1132309.602093
2645077.161386 - 1132313.996292
2645081.068384 - 1132306.244629
```

But if i use this website: https://mygeodata.cloud/cs2cs/ to convert my coordinate it give me different result:

```
2645159.23603 - 1132445.21286
2645162.29062 - 1132448.57073
2645155.32853 - 1132452.96545
2645159.23603 - 1132445.21286
```

And i realize that the result from the website above is the correct one. So what is the problem with my code? Why there is the different between my code and the result from **mygeodata**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, ArcGIS doesn't apply a datum transformation when projecting data. In your case, the target reference system is using a datum that is different from your input coordinate system (input GCS = WGS84, output GCS = Bessel 1841). Therefore, you should specify the geographic transformation to the projectAs command

```
transform = "CH1903+_To_WGS_1984_1"
ptgeo1 = ptgeo.projectAs(out_spatial,transform)
```

There are often several transform available (you can list them with `print (arcpy.ListTransformations(inspatial, outspatial))`).Most of them usually work for general purpose, but the precision varies. I took the first one available because I don't know your study area and it give the same results as in your website. If you need optimal accuracy on a given area, check [ESRI's list of transforms](http://support.esri.com/technical-article/000004829).

[image]

Comment: I have try your solution but it give me this error: ValueError: CH1903_To_WGS_1984_1 , even though i use WKID but the error still remains, you have any ideas about this problem.

Comment: sorry, spelling error, now corrected. Please try again. Note that you can check available transforms using print (arcpy.ListTransformations(in_spatial, out_spatial))

Comment: thanh you very much. you save the day